Decomposing a graph into the minimum number of edge-disjoint trees
Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, what is the minimum number of edge-disjoint trees needed to cover $G$? How can we find such a decomposition?
I've seen similar problems studied before (such as the arboricity of graphs), but I couldn't find too much on this specific problem. Any help is appreciated.

Perhaps https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895674900872 is relevant.

When you say "tree" do you mean spanning tree? If so, then such a decomposition is not always possible. If not, then maybe you are asking about arboricity where you want bounds on the number of components in the forests?

@dbal The trees don't necessarily have to be spanning. I guess one way to look at it is arboricity where each forest only has one component. Would such a decomposition not always be possible? I assumed that we can take the trivial decomposition where each edge in the graph is its own tree. Perhaps I should clarify in the question that the trees need not be vertex-disjoint?

oooh, I just found this paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-70904-6_41.pdf .
my "not always possible" comment was if you wanted the trees to be spanning

I think an algorithm to compute this is just the trivial greedy approach: keep removing the maximal dfs tree you can find from any of the non-trivial components remaining, until you are left with no edges

Intuition is that for any maximal tree, one and only one edge of the minimum cut of the graph will appear in it. This is good for us as we don't want to waste these minimum cut edges by using more than one at once, and also if we use them late, the algorithm might be inefficient. But yea I don't know how to formally prove this

Ohh I just realized that its not necessary that the maximal tree will only take one edge out of a min cut, it might take more. Thats definitely inefficient.

@dbal This paper is great! Thank you for your comments, I'll look into it a bit further.
